# Magento 2 Custom Collection

Tags: collection, grid, custom

How can I create custom collection to show data in grid in back-end. 
Example, I want to show a list of log files or show cron job tasks, The did not come from Database, just an array I collect.

Please help me.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a custom collection class and instead of extending it to the usual `Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection` you can extend it to `Magento\Framework\Data\Collection` and use the `addItem` method to add your array values as collection items.

First the we need a collection class `app/code/<Vendor>/<Module-Name>/Model/ResourceModel/Logs/Collection.php`

```
<?php
namespace <Vendor>\<Module-Name>\Model\ResourceModel\Logs;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection as DataCollection;

class Collection extends DataCollection
{

}//end class
```

Now for the Grid file `app/code/<Vendor>/<Module-Name>/Block/Adminhtml/Logs/Grid.php`

```
<?php

 namespace <Vendor>\<Module-Name>\Block\Adminhtml\Logs;

 use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;
 use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
 use Magento\Backend\Helper\Data;
 use <Vendor>\<Module-Name>\Model\ResourceModel\Logs\Collection; 

 class Grid extends Extended
 {


    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    protected $_collection;


   /**
    * Constructor
    *
    * @param Context $context
    * @param Data $backendHelper
    * @param Collection $collection
    * @param array $data
    */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Data $backendHelper,
        Collection $collection,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_collection = $collection;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }//end __construct()


   /**
    * @return void
    */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('logs_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('log_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setVarNameFilter('logs_record');
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $logData = [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'value' => "Some Value"
            ],
            [
                'id' => 2,
                'value' => "Some Another Value"
            ]
        ];
        $collection = $this->_collection;
        foreach ($logData as $data) {
            $DataObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($data);
            $collection->addItem(
                DataObject($DataObject)
            );
        }
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }//end _prepareCollection()


    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
       //Your columns
       return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }//end _prepareColumns()
}//end class
```

Comment: Thanks, Could you give me an example how I can extend and build it inside a module ?

Comment: Ya sure let me modify my answer

Comment: See if this is more helpful